Why is my projects card not getting any smaller after the screen size reaches 911 px by 911 px?
I am making a page to show my projects. It works fine on desktop and I am currently trying to make the page responsive. I am using Next.js and tailwindcss. I was able to make the page responsive up until screen sizes of 911 px by 911 px or less. Once I reach the screen size, the projects stay the same size. I wam trying to figure out why they are not shrinking further.
tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const { fontFamily } = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
  content: [
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        mont: ["var(--font-mont)", ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
      colors: {
        dark: "#1b1b1b",
        light: "#f5f5f5",
        primary: "#B63E96", 
        primaryDark: "#58E6D9",
      },
      screens: {
        "2xl": { max: "1535px" },
        // => @media (max-width: 1535px) { ... }
    
        xl: { max: "1279px" },
        // => @media (max-width: 1279px) { ... }
    
        lg: { max: "1023px" },
        // => @media (max-width: 1023px) { ... }
    
        md: { max: "767px" },
        // => @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
    
        sm: { max: "639px" },
        // => @media (max-width: 639px) { ... }
    
        xs: { max: "479px" },
        // => @media (max-width: 479px) { ... }
    },
      backgroundImage: {
        circularLight:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px,#f5f5f5 5px,#f5f5f5 100px)",

    circularDark:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 2px,#1b1b1b 8px,#1b1b1b 100px)",

    circularLightLg:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px,#f5f5f5 5px,#f5f5f5 80px)",

    circularDarkLg:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 2px,#1b1b1b 8px,#1b1b1b 80px)",

    circularLightMd:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px,#f5f5f5 5px,#f5f5f5 60px)",

    circularDarkMd:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 2px,#1b1b1b 6px,#1b1b1b 60px)",

    circularLightSm:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px,#f5f5f5 5px,#f5f5f5 40px)",

    circularDarkSm:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 2px,#1b1b1b 4px,#1b1b1b 40px)",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    function ({ addUtilities }) {
      const newUtilities = {
        ".p-6-fix": {
          padding: "1.6rem",
        },
      };

      addUtilities(newUtilities);
    },
  ],
};

Project.js code:
import AnimatedText from "@/components/AnimatedText";
import { GithubIcon } from "@/components/Icons";
import Layout from "@/components/Layout";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import project1 from "../../public/images/projects/keyword-search.png";
import project2 from "../../public/images/projects/lexflow.png";
import project3 from "../../public/images/projects/project-citizen.png";
import project4 from "../../public/images/projects/aclu-archives.png";

const FeaturedProject = ({ type, title, summary, img, link, github }) => {
  return (
    <article
      className="w-full flex items-center justify-between relative rounder-br-2xl
    rounded-3xl border border-solid border-dark bg-light shadow-2xl p-12 dark:bg-dark dark:border-light
    lg:flex-col lg:p-9 xs:rounded-2xl xs:rounded-br-3xl xs:p-4
    "
    >
      <div
        className="absolute top-0 -right-3 -z-10 w-[101%] h-[103%] rounded-[2.5rem] bg-dark dark:bg-light
      rounded-br-3xl xs:-right-2 sm:h-[102%] xs:w-full xs:rounded-[1.5rem]
      "
      />
      <Link
        href={link}
        target="_blank"
        className="w-1/2 cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg
        lg:w-full
        "
      >
        <Image
          src={img}
          alt={title}
          className="w-full h-auto transition-transform duration-300 transform hover:scale-105"
          priority
          sizes="(max-width: 768 px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 50vw"
        />
      </Link>

      <div
        className="w-1/2 flex flex-col items-start justify-between pl-6
      lg:w-full lg:pl-0 lg:pt-6
      "
      >
        <span
          className="text-primary font-medium text-xl dark:text-primaryDark
        xs:text-base
        "
        >
          {type}
        </span>
        <Link
          href={link}
          target="_blank"
          className="hover:underline underline-offset-2"
        >
          <h2
            className="my-2 w-full text-left text-4xl font-bold dark:text-light
          sm:text-sm
          "
          >
            {title}
          </h2>
        </Link>
        <p
          className="my-2 font-medium text-dark dark:text-light
        sm:text-sm
        "
        >
          {summary}
        </p>
        <div className="mt-2 flex items-center">
          <Link href={github} target="_blank" className="w-10">
            <GithubIcon />
          </Link>
          <Link
            href={link}
            target="_blank"
            className="ml-4 rounded-lg bg-dark text-light p-2 px-6 text-lg font-semibold dark:bg-light dark:text-dark
            sm:px-4 sm:text-base
            "
          >
            Visit Project
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

const FeaturedProjectNoGit = ({ type, title, summary, img, link }) => {
  return (
    <article
      className="w-full flex items-center justify-between relative rounder-br-2xl
    rounded-3xl border border-solid border-dark bg-light shadow-2xl p-12 dark:bg-dark dark:border-light
    lg:flex-col lg:p-9 xs:rounded-2xl xs:rounded-br-3xl xs:p-4
    "
    >
      <div
        className="absolute top-0 -right-3 -z-10 w-[101%] h-[103%] rounded-[2.5rem] bg-dark dark:bg-light
      rounded-br-3xl xs:-right-2 sm:h-[102%] xs:w-full xs:rounded-[1.5rem]
      "
      />
      <Link
        href={link}
        target="_blank"
        className="w-1/2 cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg
        lg:w-full
        "
      >
        <Image
          src={img}
          alt={title}
          className="w-full h-auto transition-transform duration-300 transform hover:scale-105"
          priority
          sizes="(max-width: 768 px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 50vw"
        />
      </Link>

      <div
        className="w-1/2 flex flex-col items-start justify-between pl-6
      lg:w-full lg:pl-0 lg:pt-6
      "
      >
        <span
          className="text-primary font-medium text-xl dark:text-primaryDark
        xs:text-base
        "
        >
          {type}
        </span>
        <Link
          href={link}
          target="_blank"
          className="hover:underline underline-offset-2"
        >
          <h2
            className="my-2 w-full text-left text-4xl font-bold dark:text-light
          sm:text-sm
          "
          >
            {title}
          </h2>
        </Link>
        <p
          className="my-2 font-medium text-dark dark:text-light
        sm:text-sm
        "
        >
          {summary}
        </p>
        <div className="mt-2 flex items-center">
          <Link
            href={link}
            target="_blank"
            className="ml-4 rounded-lg bg-dark text-light p-2 px-6 text-lg font-semibold dark:bg-light dark:text-dark
            sm:px-4 sm:text-base
            "
          >
            Visit Project
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

const Project = ({ type, title, img, link, github }) => {
  return (
    <article
      className="w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-2xl
    border border-solid border-dark bg-light p-6 relative dark:bg-dark dark:border-light
    xs:p-4
    "
    >
      <div
        className="absolute top-0 -right-3 -z-10 w-[101%] h-[103%] rounded-[2rem] bg-dark
      rounded-br-3xl dark:bg-light
      md:-right-2 md:w-[101%] xs:h-[102%] xs:rounded-[1.5rem]
      "
      />

      <Link
        href={link}
        target="_blank"
        className="w-full cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg"
      >
        <Image
          src={img}
          alt={title}
          className="w-full h-auto transition-transform duration-300 transform hover:scale-105"
        />
      </Link>

      <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-start justify-between mt-4">
        <span
          className="text-primary dark:text-primaryDark font-medium text-xl
        lg:text-lg md:text-base
        "
        >
          {type}
        </span>
        <Link
          href={link}
          target="_blank"
          className="hover:underline underline-offset-2"
        >
          <h2 className="my-2 w-full text-left text-4xl font-bold lg:text-2xl">
            {title}
          </h2>
        </Link>
        <div className="w-full mt-2 flex items-center justify-between">
          <Link
            href={link}
            target="_blank"
            className="text-lg font-semibold underline
            md:text-base
            "
          >
            Visit
          </Link>
          <Link
            href={github}
            target="_blank"
            className="w-8
          md:w-6
          "
          >
            <GithubIcon />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

const projects = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Projects - </title>
        <meta
          name="Projects Page for "
          content="Technology, Computer Science, Law, Coding, Web Development, Student, High School, Stanford, UPenn, Github"
        />
      </Head>
      <main className="w-full mb-16 flex flex-col items-center justify-center dark:text-light">
        <Layout className="pt-16">
          <AnimatedText
            text="I'm not a businessman, I'm a business, man."
            className="mb-16
            lg:!text-7xl sm:mb-8 sm:!text-6xl xs:!text-4xl
            "
          />

          <div
            className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-24 gap-y-32
          xl:gap-x-16 lg:gap-x-8 md:gap-y-24 md:gap sm:gap-x-0
          "
          >
            <div className="col-span-12">
              <FeaturedProject
                title="Competition Cases Keyword Search"
                img={project1}
                summary="A index where you can search keywords related to return market definitions decided in European Commission competition cases."
                link="/"
                github="/"
                type="Featured Project"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-12">
              <Project
                title="LexFlow"
                img={project2}
                link="/"
                github="/"
                type="Featured Project"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-12">
              <Project
                title="Project Citizen"
                img={project3}
                link="/l"
                github="/"
                type="Website"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-span-12">
              <FeaturedProjectNoGit
                title="ACLU of Delaware Archives"
                img={project4}
                summary="The ACLU of Delaware Archives preserves the organization's history and ongoing efforts to protect civil liberties in Delaware.
                These archives showcase important legal cases, campaigns, and advocacy efforts the ACLU has worked on, including education
                reform and voting rights. The archives serve as a resource for understanding the impact of the ACLU's work in Delaware over
                the years."
                link="https://www.aclu-de.org/en/archives"
                type="Archival Project"
              />
            </div>
            {/* //TODO: add another featured project */}
            {/* <div className="col-span-12">Featured Project</div> */}
            {/* //TODO: add another project */}
            {/* <div className="col-span-6">Project-4</div> */}
          </div>
        </Layout>
      </main>
    </>[![[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/trkhVCXy.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/trkhVCXy.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/yr6xYOt0.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/yr6xYOt0.png)
  );
};

export default projects;
[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/j3vpz8Fd.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/j3vpz8Fd.png)

I've tried changing the width, the gaps, the columns, and the grid layout but nothing worked. Either I made the wrong changes or I was making changes in the wrong place.
[]
[

You should avoid using vw type units for embedded content such as images, and also avoid using bracketed values such as -[value] as much as possible. To solve your problem we don't have your tailwindcss configuration because it is mobile-first by default, which may be where your problem comes from.

I added my tailwind.config.js file to my post. Let me know if you can find out anything from that.
